# Open product neighbourhoods

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $X\times Y$ be a topological space (if it helps anything, it can be assumed to be a smooth manifold and $U\subseteq X\times Y$ an open subset.

Let $x\in X$ and $O\subseteq Y$ be open, such that $\{x\}\times O\subseteq U$. Does there exist an open $V\subseteq X$ with $x\in V$ and $V\times O\subseteq U$?

This above question got a negative answer. Let me ask instead the following:

Let in addition $C\subseteq Y$ be a closed set, such that $C\subseteq O$. Does there exist an open $V\subseteq X$ and an open $C\subseteq O'\subseteq Y$ with $x\in V$ and $V\times O'\subseteq U$?

Comment: Maybe. Not necessarily. Try to find examples where such a $V$ doesn't exist in familiar settings, say $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What if we require $X$ to be compact, say $X=[0,1]$?

Comment: That doesn't change things.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X=Y=[0,1]$ let

$$U=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y : x+y< 1/2\}.$$

Then $\{0\}\times (0,1/2)\subseteq U$, however any open set around $\{0\}$ in $X$ contains an interval, $[0,b)$ and if $[0,b)\times (0,1/2)\subseteq U$ we can note that this implies $(b,{1-b\over 2})\in U$ which is impossible as $(1-b)/2+b=(1+b)/2>{1\over 2}$.

The modified question is pretty much trivial. Since you don't mind if we assume a smooth manifold, I will. Then the basic separation axioms say that every point has a basis of compact neighborhoods (i.e. compact--hence closed--sets containing an open set). So if you pick any point in $\{x\}\times O$, hence in $U$, we can find a closed set containing an open set which is totally contained in any open set that the point is contained in. Then by the definition of the product topology, we have that all open sets contain a set of the form $A\times B$ with $A,B$ open in $X,Y$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you. I added a new modified question which rules out this counterexample. Do you have any idea for the edited question?

Comment: @Carl Generally you want to post new questions in new topics and link old ones for motivation when necessary:  constant editing can get tiresome and confusing for posters. That said:  the same counterexample works, making the second set bigger only makes it **more** of a problem, not less, and allowing the second set to be smaller makes the problem trivial:  by definition of the product topology you can always find such a product with a smaller second set. See my edited answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. It should have been $C\subseteq O$ instead of $O\subseteq C$

Comment: @Carl sorry about the edit rollback, your edited question was slightly less trivial because of the set $C$, but it's still pretty easy to deal with.